# rail fence cipher algorithm c

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, cryptography

i am writing a rail fence cipher algorithm in c for fun and to brush up on my C programming skills. i have it working well for smallish input phrases, but it gets garbled for some reason when the input phrase is large.

here is the code: (sorry, i couldnt reduce it to a SSCCE, i dont know which part of the algorithm is causing the problem)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* function to append a char to a char array */
void append(char* s, char c)
{
   int len = strlen(s);
   s[len] = c;
   s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
   int num_rails;

   for (num_rails = 2; num_rails < 6; num_rails++)
   {

   char* message = "therailfencecipheristrickyespeciallywhentheinputisverylongabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzblerpblorp";

   int word_len = strlen(message);

   char* lines[num_rails];
   char* rails[num_rails];

   int len_rails[num_rails];
   memset(len_rails, 0, num_rails*sizeof(int));

   int i,j,k,mod;
   int repeats;
   int period = (2*num_rails) - 2;

   printf("%d characters, %d rails:\n", word_len, num_rails);

   printf("\nplaintext: %s\n", message);

   /* encryption */

   for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
   {
      if ((lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL)
      {
         printf("\nUnable to allocate memory.\n");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }

   for (repeats = 0; repeats < ((word_len/period)+1); repeats++)
   {
      if (repeats*period < word_len)
         append(lines[0], message[repeats*period]);

      for (j = 1; j < period/2; j++)
      {
         if ((j + (repeats*period)) < word_len)
            append(lines[j], message[j + (repeats*period)]);

         if ((((repeats+1)*period) - j) < word_len)
            append(lines[j], message[((repeats+1)*period) - j]);
      }

      if (((period/2) + (repeats*period)) < word_len)
         append(lines[j], message[(period/2)+(repeats*period)]);
   }

   char encrypted[word_len];
   strcpy(encrypted,lines[0]);

   for (i = 1; i < num_rails; i++)
      strcat(encrypted, lines[i]);

   printf("\nciphertext: %s\n", encrypted);

   /* decryption */

   for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
   {
      if ((rails[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 40)) == NULL)
      {
         printf("\nUnable to allocate memory.\n");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }

   mod = word_len % period;

   len_rails[0] = word_len / period;
   len_rails[num_rails-1] = len_rails[0];

   for (i = 1; i < num_rails - 1; i++)
      len_rails[i] = len_rails[0] * 2;

   for (i = 0; i < mod && i < num_rails; i++)
   {
      len_rails[i]++;
   }

   for (j = i-2; i < mod && j > -1; j--)
   {
      len_rails[j]++;
      i++;
   }

   printf("\nrail lengths:");
   for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
      printf(" %d", len_rails[i]);

   putchar('\n');
   k = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < len_rails[i]; j++)
      {
         append(rails[i], encrypted[k++]);
      }
   }

   char deciphered[word_len];
   strcpy(deciphered, "");

   for (i = 0; i < ((word_len/period)+1); i++)
   {
      if (rails[0][i])
         append(deciphered, rails[0][i]);

      for (j = 1; j < num_rails-1; j++)
      {
         if (rails[j][i*2])
            append(deciphered, rails[j][i*2]);
      }

      if (rails[num_rails-1][i])
         append(deciphered, rails[num_rails-1][i]);

      for (j = num_rails-2; j > 0; j--)
      {
         if (rails[j][(i*2)+1])
            append(deciphered, rails[j][(i*2)+1]);
      }
   }

   printf("\ndeciphered: %s\n", deciphered);

   printf("==========================================\n");
   }
}
```

it should compile and run fine so you can test it.

it is supposed to print the plain text, then encipher it and print that, then decipher the enciphered text back to plain text and print that for 2, 3, 4, 5 rails but it should work for any number of rails.

the problem is that the output gets garbled if the input variable "message" gets over a certain size for different numbers of rails.

eg.

2 rails becomes garbled at 63 characters

3 rails becomes garbled at 64 characters

4 rails becomes garbled at 95 characters

5 rails becomes garbled at 126 characters

etc.

the closest i have been able to come to working out what is wrong is that whenever any value for len_rails[] exceeds 31 the output gets garbled for that amount of rails..

does anyone have any idea why this would be? is it to do with how i am allocating memory? its been a while since i did any C programming and my memory handling is a bit rusty.

any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
if ((lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL)
```

you are only allocating memory for a single char, but then try to use the buffer for storing much more than one `char` of data. Multiply `sizeof(char)` (which is, by the way, always 1) by the number of chars you are planning to store in the array.

Remember to free() the memory just before the end.

Comment: hahaha, im an idiot, sorry, i multiplied it by half the length of the input and it worked, thanks again!

Comment: You need to declare some string array at least 5*126 so larger than 600, so       ** char input[1024];  ** and so on, depending on how big the longest string will grow to be.